# Are asynchronous javascript HTTP requests sent before or after the main stack completes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

assume the following:

```
http.get('mycoolwebsite.com/somecontent', function(){
    console.log('printed');
}

doSomeReallyIntensive100Hourwork();
```

I understand that we will see the word 'printed' printed on the console after 100 hours.

**The questions:**

Does javascript delay the request after 100 hours and then execute the callback or does it send out a request immediately and schedule the callback to print later? Basically, do we immediately notice the network request or not?

Comment: Where is reference to "100 hours" derived from?

Comment: Network request will be fired right away because it's asynchronous (read about event loops). But even if there's a response ready to be printed it will be printed after that heavy function will finish its execution because console.log printing and this heavy function are doing the job on the same thread. Until `doSomeReallyIntensive100Hourwork` is finished the thread is blocked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jimmyweb.

Comment: @guest271314 it's the example function above.

Comment: Run this ->   (function(){
 console.log("initial Request");
 setTimeout((e)=>console.log("callback"), 0)
})();
(function(){
 let a = 1;
  while(a < 1000000000){a++}
 console.log("finished loop")
})() 
//
 initial Request
 finished loop
 callback

Answer (score 1):

The request is initiated immediately, and the response will possibly also have arrived, but your `get` callback function will be triggered by an event in the event queue which only gets processed in the next task.

From [mdn on `XMLHttpRequest.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send), the method that is executed under the hood of the `http.get` method:

> The `XMLHttpRequest.send()` method sends the request. If the request is asynchronous (which is the default), this method returns as soon as the request is sent.

Note the last part. See also the [WHATWG standards, section 4.5.6](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method):

> The `send(body)` method must run these steps:
>
> 10.4.1 Wait until either *req*’s done flag is set or
>
> 1. the `timeout` attribute value number of milliseconds has passed since these subsubsteps started
> 2. while `timeout` attribute value is not zero.

... so the method *does* wait to make sure the request has been sent (or a timeout occurred).

Here is a demo with an HTTP call to a service that answers after a 2 second server-sided wait. You can launch it in two ways: with or without the intensive work.

When using the option to not do the work, the response comes back about 2 seconds after the click. If using the other option (with the work), then the work is done after three seconds and the response is processed immediately afterwards (have some patience after clicking):

```js
function work() {
    // Be busy for 3 seconds
    var until = performance.now() + 3000;
    while (performance.now() < until);
    console.log('hard work done');
}

function test(work) {
    $.get("http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=2000", function() {
        console.log('response processed');
    });
    if (work) work();
}

$('#without').click(test.bind(null, null));
$('#with').click(test.bind(null, work));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="with">Request with 3 secs of work</button>
<button id="without">Reguest without that work</button>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the specs that *requires* the request to be initiated immediately? I'd think that after calling the XHR `send()` method, it's really out of our control what happens in the browser with it. E.g. DOM rendering waits until after the hard work is finished as well.

Comment: I added some references, @Bergi.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't actually wait for 10.4 (or else all requests would be synchronous): "*Run these subsubsteps [in parallel](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel):*".

Comment: @Bergi, as I understand it 10.4 is not about waiting for the response (which indeed would make it behave as a synchronous request) but about the successful submission of the request itself. At least the mdn article seems to claim the sending happens before the JS call returns (but mdn is of course not the final authority)

Comment: I think it's 10.4 "*Fetch `req`"* that is actually sending the request (and MDN is right). That's the last step that happens synchronously, then `send` returns. The substeps about waiting for the response will happen in parallel, and lead to asynchronous events.

Comment: Yes that is also how I understood it.

Comment: @trincot, thank you for your answer. It is really informative. I believe that the main idea here is that once javascript hits the request line, it does trigger the browser/server to do something in a process that is *outside* of javascript. The external process will get the information and makes its way back and notify javascript and then javascript will get back to the results when no script is being executed. Am I on the right path here?

Comment: My understanding is that JavaScript will block briefly while the request is being sent (which on the lower TCP level [involves several steps](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/17/anatomyhttp/)), but once the HTTP send operation was performed (by the browser stack), the JS engine will continue its code execution. The browser internals will be monitoring the response (probably in parallel with JS execution) and as soon as that response is detected, an event will be injected in the JS queue. The JS engine will only process the event queue when its current task has finished.

Answer (score 1):

> do we immediately notice the network request or not?

That's up to the browser. JS will immediately tell the browser that it should execute the following request, but it's up to the browser to decide wether it has the capacity to immediately start this request or wether to queue it untill there are ressources available.

Then, eventually the request is sent, the response is there, and the browser will notify JS that the request is done, and pass the recieved data. Then JS, as soon as JS is idle*, it will call the callback-function.

*JS is single-threaded. It can't run two pieces of code at once, and it won't interrupt some other code to run your callback-function. It will call it as soon as there is no other pending Javascript to run.*